# sample video file encoding in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I can encode and decode a test video with following pipelines:

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v videotestsrc num-buffers=2000 ! TIVidenc1 codecName=h264enc engineName=codecServer ! filesink location=sample.264

gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=sample.264 ! TIViddec2 codecName=h264dec engineName=codecServer ! filesink location=sample.raw
```

but I can’t encode a sample raw video file like sample.raw with following pipelines:

1. gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=sample.raw  num-buffers=2000 ! TIVidenc1 codecName=h264enc engineName=codecServer ! filesink location=sample.264

   ERROR: failed to create video encoder h264enc
2. gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=sample.raw  num-buffers=2000 ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=320,height=240,framerate=30 ! TIVidenc1 codecName=h264enc engineName=codecServer ! filesink location=sample.264

   ERROR: could not link filesrc0 to tividenc10

Answer (score 0):

You will need the [videoparse](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-videoparse.html) element after the filesource element. This takes care of the proper parsing and media type offering for the encoder.